# Get the UserID of the current logged in User in asp.net default membership provider

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, asp.net-membership

I have two tables

```
Employee (EmpID, Name, UpdatedBy, UpdateDate)
EmpContact (ContactID, Contact,EmpID)
```

I am trying to create a trigger which update a Employee table fields `UpdatedBy,UpdateDate`. when contact is added or modified i want to update Employee's `UpdatedBy and UpdateDate` fields  (These two tables have different asp.net-mvc views).
 I am using default membership provider to authenticate the user.
 So my question is how **can i get the current logged in user in trigger who initiated the insert, update or delete. Is there any way i can know which asp.net user id initiated the transaction within the TRIGGER**

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to know how to create a SQL-Server trigger that updates your Employee table when an EmpContact record is created(edited,deleted)?!

Comment: yes but main problem is how to get the current  loggin useID of which behalf modification is done. that user id is not database user but membership provider user who logged in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an insert/update/delete trigger that updates the Emplyoee table when records in EmpContact are created/updated/deleted, for example(insert):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgCreateEmpContact] ON [dbo].[EmpContact]
FOR INSERT
AS

UPDATE dbo.Employee
SET UpdateDate=GetDate(), UpdatedBy = I.UpdatedBy
FROM Employee E
INNER JOIN Inserted I ON E.EmpID = I.EmpID
```

So you need to add the `UpdatedBy` column to your EmpContact table too.

You get the current logged in user in the following way:

```
MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
GUID currentUserID = (GUID)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
```

Another(better) approach would be to create a stored-procedure that internally creates the EmpContact record and updates the Employee table in a transaction, for example(untested):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertEmpContact]
    @ContactID int OUTPUT,
    @Contact varchar(50) OUTPUT,
    @EmpID int OUTPUT,
    @UpdateDate datetime OUTPUT,
    @UpdatedBy int OUTPUT,
 with execute as Owner
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO EmpContact(Contact, EmpID)
VALUES     (@Contact,@EmpID)

;SELECT  @ContactID=ContactID,@Contact=Contact,@EmpID=EmpID,@UpdateDate=GetDate()
FROM EmpContact WHERE (ContactID = SCOPE_IDENTITY())

;UPDATE dbo.Employee
SET UpdateDate=@UpdateDate, UpdatedBy = @UpdatedBy
WHERE EmpID = @EmpID 

IF @@ERROR <> 0
 BEGIN
    -- Rollback the transaction
    ROLLBACK
    RETURN
 END

COMMIT
```

Comment: Hmm So i have to add the UpdatedBy column in EmpContact also. I was searching a way to avoid that. If it is the last resort i will do it

Comment: @Tassadaque: edited my answer and provided a way to avoid that. Create a SP for inserting/editing and deleting records that updates the employee table internally in a transaction. That would be the most robust and readable solution. Triggers are anyway often too much magic in background.

Comment: Thanks but I am using entity framework for insert writing my own insert procedure is not an option for me at the moment :(

Comment: @Tassadaque: it should be possible to use SO in EF as well: http://thedatafarm.com/LearnEntityFramework/tutorials/using-stored-procedures-for-insert-update-amp-delete-in-an-entity-data-model/ and http://weblogs.asp.net/kencox/archive/2009/11/25/using-a-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-4.aspx

Comment: Note: I meant SP(Stored-Procedure) instead of SO.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Hey I have something similar setup to this my update and insert gets the user name, I am using session parameter for updatedBy column but what about deleting there is no parameter required so while deleting the updatedBy column doesn't have current user instead previous user who updated it. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect the current logged in user from memebership please use these links

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CustomMembershipProviders.aspx

http://theintegrity.co.uk/2010/11/asp-net-mvc-2-custom-membership-provider-tutorial-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your app connects to your database. If you do it, like almost all of us, with connection pooling and a single user connecting to the database, the answer is no, you cannot know that in the trigger.

E.g. the app connects to the database as sa/pwd (not advisable, but for arguments sake only).

If user one (Paul) connects to the db and does an update, your trigger will get sa as user.
If user two (Anne) connects to the db, the trigger will also get sa as user.

So you need to include the update of the user in the update statmement (or as an argument to your stored procedure)